# vercel deployment unable to require `.d.ts` file

Tags: typescript, next.js, vercel

My next.js app works on my machine but when deployed on Vercel, it fails while building with the following error:

```
Error! Unable to require `.d.ts` file.
This is usually the result of a faulty configuration or import. Make sure there is a `.js`, `.json` or another executable extension and loader (attached before `ts-node`) available alongside `emotion.d.ts`.
```

It seemed it could not detect emotion.d.ts in my types folder. It is located in src like /src/types/emotion.d.ts, so I tried to change my settings to include that as follows.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve"
  },
  "include": [
    "next-env.d.ts",
    "src/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Still, no luck.

My emotion.d.ts file simply declares a type like this.

```
import '@emotion/react';

declare module '@emotion/react' {
  export interface Theme {
    color: {
      primary0: string;
      primary1: string;
      primary2: string;
      primary3: string;
      primary4: string;
      primary5: string;
      primary6: string;
      primary7: string;
      secondary0: string;
      secondary1: string;
      secondary2: string;
      secondary3: string;
      secondary4: string;
      secondary5: string;
      secondary6: string;
      tertiary0: string;
      tertiary1: string;
      tertiary2: string;
      text0: string;
      text1: string;
      text2: string;
      text3: string;
      text4: string;
      bg0: string;
      bg1: string;
      bg2: string;
    };
    size: {
      maxWidth: string;
    };
    mediaQuery: {
      sp: string;
      pc: string;
    };
  }
}
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Try to add `emotion.d.ts` to `include` property in tsconfig

Comment: okay, I will. Thank you.